# R Select row with lowest numbers and NA's

Tags: r

How I can select the row with the lowest values inside a data frame?
I don't search for the lowest value. My interest is for which row all values are lower in comparison to the other rows. Maybe it works without the mean value per row.

Because my `data.frame` is really huge some ranking would be not so bad, either.

Some example Code:

```
  v1 <- rnorm(n=10, mean=2, sd=0.55)
  ind <- which(v1 %in% sample(v1, 3))
  v1[ind]<-NA

  v2 <- rnorm(n=10, mean=1, sd=0.3)
  ind <- which(v2 %in% sample(v2, 5))
  v2[ind]<-NA

  v3 <- rnorm(n=10, mean=0.5, sd=0.3)
  ind <- which(v3 %in% sample(v3, 4))
  v3[ind]<-NA

  v4 <- rnorm(n=10, mean=4, sd=1)
  ind <- which(v4 %in% sample(v4, 2))
  v4[ind]<-NA

  v5 <- rnorm(n=10, mean=3, sd=2)
  ind <- which(v5 %in% sample(v5, 1))
  v5[ind]<-NA

  df<-data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
```

Comment: How many rows you want to select? What you expected output?

Comment: It would be nice if there are three rows where the values are lower than in the other rows.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the lowest total value, so add a total column, ignoring the NA values, arrange by total, slice to see your low value.

```
df$total <- rowSums(df,na.rm = TRUE)

df %>% arrange(total) %>% slice(1)
```

Note, there's probably a way to do the whole thing in `dplyr` but I've never really figured out how to make colSums work against a whole tibble/df that you are passing via the pipe. If anyone knows how to do that it would be useful to know!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No I don't search for the lowest total value. I search for a row where the numbers are smaller than in the other rows.

Comment: shouldn't it be `rowSums` ? OP wants to rank the rows by # of NAs

Comment: @Hark what do you mean by that? do you mean the row where the mean value is the lowest? the median?

Comment: @Randall Helms The mean value won't work because in my real data frame the number of NA's is too different.  Maybe there is no statistical size which solve my problem.